# Evaluate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a}{a+b}n)}{n^3}+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi b}{a+b}n)}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-series

I have to evaluate the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a}{a+b}n)}{n^3}+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi b}{a+b}n)}{n^3}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Since I'm not very good with series I tried brute force by using a complex analysis method which involves multiplying by the cotangent and calculating the residue at $n=0$ (I don't know the name of this method, sorry!), but I didn't get the result my teacher gave me.

I figured this is the Fourier series expansion of some odd function, but I don't know how to guess said function.

So I was wondering if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: You mean you tried the (Cauchy's) Residue Theorem perhaps?

Comment: It's based on that, it's the method mentioned (for example) in this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575750/evaluating-series-by-contour-integration-the-residue-theorem-and-cotangent

Comment: At least we can tell the series is not divergent since $\sin(x)\leq1 \forall x$

Comment: The reason that the proposed methodology in the OP doesn't work here is that we need to find a function $f$ such that $\lim_{N\to \infty}\oint_{C_N}f(z) \cot(z)\,dz=0$, where $C_N$ is the classical square contour centered at the origin with sides of length $2N+1$.  But the function $\frac{\sin(\alpha z)}{z^3}$, $\alpha = \pi a/(a+b)$ or $\alpha =\pi  b/(a+b)$ is unbounded on that contour.  In fact, $\frac{e^{i \alpha z}}{z^3}$ is unbounded in the lower-half plane for $\alpha >0$ on $C_N$.  So, it appears that another tact is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite the series as

$$
S(a,b)=\Im\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(e^{\pi i a/(a+b)})^n}{n^3}+\frac{(e^{\pi i b/(a+b)})^n}{n^3}\right]
$$

Now we can apply the definition of the polylogarithmic functions

$$
\text{Li}_m(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^m}
$$

we therefore obtain

> $$
> S(a,b)=\Im\left[\text{Li}_3(e^{\pi i a/(a+b)})+\text{Li}_3(e^{\pi i b/(a+b)})\right] \quad (*)
> $$

which is i fear the best one can do for arbritary $a,b$. For example if $a,b $ are natural numbers we may rewrite this as a finite sum over Hurwitz Zeta values.

An alternative representation is terms of Clausen functions $\text{Si}_m(z)$

$$
S(a,b)=\text{Si}_3(e^{\pi i a/(a+b)})+\text{Si}_3(e^{\pi i b/(a+b)})
$$

For the special values $a=b$, $a=0$ we might find the particulary nice results

$$
S(a,a)=\frac{\pi^3}{16} \quad \\
S(0,b)=0 \quad 
$$

All defintions i used and much more can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)

Comment: And that is all she wrote.  +1 ... One could make use of the identity $z-\bar z=2i \text{Im}(z)$ to get rid of the imaginary part operator.  But that doesn't do much.  And one might also observe that $e^{i\pi b/(b+a) }=-1e^{-i\pi a/(a+b)}$, but that doesn't help much either.

Comment: @Dr. MV Good Jesus i was taking an absolute value :(

Comment: I thought so.  It was a valid attempt.  I really don't think its expressible in terms of elementary functions for general $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Dr.MV shocking stupidity from my side, i'm very sorry!
At least one could rewrite it in terms of on trilog

Comment: Tired, it wasn't stupidity.  I call this error type an oversight or in my case carelessness (or even wrecklessness).  And no need at all to apologize.  - Mark

Comment: First of all thank you both for the effort. I don't know what to think of this exercise, I tried the cotangent/residue method that I mentioned in the OP and linked in comments and it gives an explicit result, but I reckon my case doesn't fall under the hypotheses under which I can use it.

Comment: @Dr MV at least the cases where $a,b$ are natural numbers with $b-a=1$ seems to yield multiplies of Pi^3 interesting (numerically)

Comment: @DR10 would u mind us to show the result of ur teacher?

Comment: I worked it backward because there's some additional analysis to be done here after evaluating the series.
Anyway it should be:
$$\frac{\pi^3}{4(a+b)^2} ab$$

Comment: hmm i checked this for a few integer values ($a=2,b=7$,$a=3,b=9$) and this seems indeed to hold also for $a=e,b=\pi$ so i really suspect we are missing something here

Comment: The only alternative way I tried was to write the sum of sines as a product of a cosine time sine but I didn't manage to do much more.
I'll hand the exercise to the teacher anyway and if no one gives the answer I'm going to ask him for the solution and provide it, as it seems it caused a little bit of curiosity :)
Thanks again.

Comment: i tnik this can be somehow deduced from the fact that the clausen functions $Si_3(x)$ have indeed closed form. check this out:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html